# How do you open and close a gui in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I am making a game in Roblox and I came across an error. I am trying to make gui button that opens the shop in the game. But it does not open.

I'v tried to make the button not visible and the shop visible. Everything is workig fine but the guis do not become visible/invisible. It says the change to the gui's visibility in the proproties, but it does not show it in the game. I also tryed to change the gui's parent, it works for closing but not opening.

```
gui = game.StarterGui.ShopSelection
button = game.StarterGui.Shop.Button
button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    gui.Visible = true
    button.Parent.Visible = false
end)
```

This is supposed to open the ShopSelection gui and close the Shop gui when the Shop gui's button is pressed. It is not working. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're accessing the object from the `StarterGui` service. `StarterGui` clones its contents into the player's `PlayerGui` folder once the player loads. Thus, you need to access the object from there. To do this, we'll use a `LocalScript` and access the folder through the `LocalPlayer` object. As a note, `LocalScripts` can only run in places, which are direct descendants of the player, like `StarterPack`, `StarterPlayerScripts`, `StarterCharacterScripts`, or `StarterGui`.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local gui = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild("ShopSelection") --wait for objects
local button = player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("Shop") --:WaitForChild() yields the thread until the given object is found, so we don't have to wait anymore.

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    gui.Visible = true
    button.Visible = false
end)
```

Hope this helps!