# Im trying to make a Roblox GUI that changes a text but its not working

Tags: lua, roblox

```
game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()       
        game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.Text = ("Clicked")
        wait(1)
        game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextButton.Text = ("CLICK ME.")
end)
```

I'm new to programming in Roblox Studio so I am probably doing a simple mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you open and close a gui in Roblox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676724/how-do-you-open-and-close-a-gui-in-roblox)

Comment: Try getting rid of the brackets around the strings as they aren't needed and might be interfering.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is you are using a script underneath Workspace instead of under StarterGui.

You will notice when you test a game that all of the items under StarterGui get moved under the Player objects in "Players". You need to move move this script inside of the ScreenGui and reference it as follows:

```
-- Parent object
local screenUI = script.Parent

screenUI.TextButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()       
    screenUI.TextButton.Text = ("Clicked")
    wait(1)
    screenUI.TextButton.Text = ("CLICK ME.")
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your doing this within a LocalScript which is inside of the `TextLabel`, `StarterPlayer`, or somewhere within the GUI. You can't manipulate UI with a server-side script. Your code should look like this:

```
local button = script.Parent --This can vary depending on where the Script is located

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    button.Text = "Clicked"
    wait(1)
    button.Text = "CLICK ME."
end)
```